# mysql: query to display data from previous day doesnt work when its a new month

Tags: mysql

When I run the below query on the first on a month it returns no data. It is supposed to display the previous day.
The query works ok normally except when it’s the first on the month, am I doing something wrong which will not allow it to see the previous days data as it’s a previous month?

```
select COUNT(*) from osticket.ost_ticket where  DATE(created) = DATE(NOW())-1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [DATE_SUB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) :

```
 select COUNT(*)
   from osticket.ost_ticket
  where  DATE(created) = DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY));
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick answer however I have tried running this and it brings back no results when it should.

Comment: Are you sure you have data at the previous day's date ? You may want to fetch the most recent row before now() if you're not sure you always have a row the exact previous day.

Comment: Hi, yes i am am sure I have data for the previous day. I have a similer query that displays the current days data. Yesterday when I ran this it displayed data.
    select COUNT(*) from osticket.ost_ticket where  DATE(created) = DATE(NOW())

Comment: I have now fixed this, the dba I work with cracked it, the correct query is: 
    select COUNT(*) from osticket.ost_ticket where DATE(created) = DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)); Thanks to dystroy with your help as your answer was a step towards solving this.

Comment: Sorry for inexactitude, Jonathan. I update my answer so that it may help somebody else.